# .action extension... what is it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I've never come across this extension before. It's being used for a front-end interface to a j2ee backend.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's probably just a URL pattern for firing a Struts action. Most people stick with the .do convention, but you can make the actions fire on just about anything you want.

See Section 5.4.2 on [this site](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html) for more info

Answer (score 2):

This is servlet mapping in j2ee application where you can define the url pattern for a particular servlet and you can name it as you want in this one it name like .action you can give like .yourname or anything.
This mapping you can give in your web.xml using servlet-mapping tag and url-patten tag in it.

Thanks