# what does '.action' mean in a robots.txt file?

Tags: web-scraping, robots.txt

I'm looking at a `robots.txt` file that includes a line `Disallow: /path/p.action`. I would understad if it said `/path/p*` as forbidding accessing any page that begins with p. But what does `action` refer to?

Comment: It refers to whatever the webserver decides it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks robots not to fetch any path starting with `/path/p.action`.

`.action` usually indicates that there is Java code running on the server.  See [.action extension... what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369591/action-extension-what-is-it)